# How to code bulk order form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

We developing a website for wholesale marketer,
In this when user click on products for eg. if user see t-shirt, he can choose multiple sizes, colors at a time and if user select 3 sizes for a product then in an increment box value show as 3

is this possible in wordpress without using paid plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this free plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-quick-order-table-view/

It has Lightbox view for more details on the same page for each product also.

Comment: But as per above description( if user select t-shirt, he can choose multiple sizes, colors at a time and if user select 3 sizes for a product then in an increment box value show as 3), we want multi select attribute functionality, in woo commerce.